# Можно ли встроить PWA сайта в Android приложение?

Tags: java, android, pwa

У веб-сайта, которым я пользуюсь, есть PWA (Progressive Web App). Можно ли как-то встроить его в своё Android Java приложение, при этом сохранить его функциональность (уведомления и т.п.)? То есть мне нужно, чтобы при переходе на активити этого сайта, открывалось данное PWA (например).

Comment: Вроде бы что-то такое можно, хотя и не точно. Попробуйте в `chrome tab` сайт открыть и посмотреть что получится.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, спасибо. Это то, что мне нужно!